# Android:Clear the previous data and show in textview

Tags: android, textview

I am making an app in which i have to fill the dynamic text in text view but my problem is that in few cases my data is coming properly but sometimes in any textview some data is getting missed and on another click the rest of data is coming.Now i want that if the data is not coming in text box , the next time text box should not show previous data.Instead it **should show fresh data instead of previoud data**and i am using **textView.setText("")**.My code is as follows:

```
image1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            if (isFirstImage)
            {


                text2.setText("");

                System.out.println("text2"+text2.toString());
                applyRotation(0, -90);
                isFirstImage = !isFirstImage;
                Typeface tf2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/CataneoLightbT.ttf");


                text1.setText(textHeadLine);
                text2.setText(textDesc);
                text1.setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
                text2.setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

                System.out.println("Headline::  "+textHeadLine);
                System.out.println("textDesc::  "+textDesc);
                System.out.println(GalleryNewActivity.parsedExampleImageDesc.get(GalleryNewActivity.positionDesc).toString());
                System.out.println(GalleryNewActivity.parsedExampleImageHeadLine.get(GalleryNewActivity.positionDesc).toString());
                text1.setTypeface(tf2);
                text2.setTypeface(tf2);

                text1.setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
                text2.setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

                text1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                text2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);






            } else
            {

                Typeface tf2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/CataneoLightbT.ttf");
                text1.setText(textHeadLine);
                text2.setText(textDesc);

                text1.setTypeface(tf2);
                text2.setTypeface(tf2);

                applyRotation(0, 90);


                isFirstImage = !isFirstImage;

                //text1.setText("");

                text1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                text2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                text2.invalidate();
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Does making a call to `invalidate()` help after making the call to setText?

Comment: did not understand. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
image1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        if (isFirstImage)
        {
            System.out.println("text2"+text2.toString());
            applyRotation(0, -90);
            isFirstImage = !isFirstImage;
            Typeface tf2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/CataneoLightbT.ttf");

            text1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            text2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            text1.setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            text2.setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
             text1.setTypeface(tf2);
            text2.setTypeface(tf2);

            text1.setText(textHeadLine);
            text2.setText(textDesc);

            System.out.println("Headline::  "+textHeadLine);
            System.out.println("textDesc::  "+textDesc);
            System.out.println(GalleryNewActivity.parsedExampleImageDesc.get(GalleryNewActivity.positionDesc).toString());
            System.out.println(GalleryNewActivity.parsedExampleImageHeadLine.get(GalleryNewActivity.positionDesc).toString());

             view.invalidate();

        } else
        {

            applyRotation(0, 90);

            isFirstImage = !isFirstImage;

            text1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            text2.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            view.invalidate();
        }
    }
});

}
```